# Where is Rails finding the applications-xxx.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm having a problem because, having edited one of my JS files, the changes are not reflected in my browser in development. Running Rails 5.1, Puma, Safari browser. I've tried clearing caches, hard refresh, clearing cookies, stopping and restarting Puma, and sacrificing a chicken (okay, I didn't actually do that last one). All of my JS is in application-729ff72de348a230eab8cc8838363396d87b8306277789fa2085e312b166792a.js, but I can find no such file on my system. I've cleared all of the JS files from public/assets (BTW, the server says it's getting assets from "/assets_dev/" and I don't have an "assets_dev" folder). My application.rb has `config.assets.enabled = true`, `config.assets.version = '1.0'`, `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`, and my development.rb has `config.assets.compress = false`, `config.assets.debug = false`, and `config.assets.prefix = "/assets_dev"`.

Comment: I think it is in public folder, can you check public folder, it may become public/assets/...

Comment: Try precompiling your assets using 'rake assets:precompile'